# Disable Time Machine reminder on Mac

Tags: macos, time-machine, reminder

While giving a presentation in Keynote for a job interview, the presentation suddenly exit and I got a Time Machine message telling me that the last backup was more than x days ago, which was very bad timing. Is there a way to disable this reminder? I can see from the menubar icon whether Time Machine thinks I should do a backup (from the ! symbol) and I don't need an additional reminder that interrupts presentations... Any ideas?

Comment: It is better to backup minimum every day :)

Comment: Related to [this question on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69036/how-to-disable-or-delay-time-machine-hasnt-backed-up-your-computer-in-x-days), which unfortunately doesn't have a good answer yet IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I think by clicking on the time machine logo in the menubar and opening time machine preferences and turning off hourly/daily backups it will stop the messages

Answer (score 0):

I think it maybe because there are 'ghost' references to the backup drive in /Volumes.

I've just removed all mine as I also am getting the annoying pop up.  If it no longer pops up I'll update here.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "removing ghost references" by [edit]ing your answer.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/20879/how-to-remove-duplicate-ghost-network-drive-on-os-x see first answer here.  So far I've had no time machine popups since removing ghost references.

Comment: Well bang goes my theory, the damned message has just popped up :(